# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (React Production Build)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Всем привет, я написал свой React-проект и сбилдил его для продакшена с помощью команды

> npm run build

Какое-то время всё работало без проблем, однако теперь появилась какая-то проблема, которую я не могу исправить.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'   (main.6eb8727b.chunk.js:1)

Кто-то сталкивался с таким? Как вы решили эту проблему?

Comment: Вы весь текст ошибки написали? Скорее всего там есть еще строки.

Comment: у вас все работало, вы ничего не меняли и больше не работает?

Comment: у вас где-то лишний оператор '<'

Comment: Что у вас этот запрос вообще возвращает? Посмотрите в консоли разработчика браузера. Подозреваю, что там что-то с `<DOCTYPE` приходит.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica да, там в js файле HTML код, но я не знаю, как это происходит

Comment: @Lofectr. спасибо, капитан очевидность

Comment: @AlexDevTime нет, только это строка.

Comment: Покажите, что там по факту приходит и какой http status code. Подозреваю, что вам сервак html отдаёт с 404 ошибкой.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica это плавающий баг. Я его ловлю спонтанно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ я на этот баг так и не нашёл, так как он пропал. Однако если у кого возникнет такая проблема, то попробуйте [serve](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) вместо nginx/apache.